# numpy array with Pillow's getcolors' dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

Pretty self-explanatory. Pillow's `getcolors()` method returns list of tuples, each with a `(1,3)` shape (i.e. `(count, (r, g, b))` ). Unless there is a better way to handle this, how can I create a numpy array with a `[n, [1, 3]]` shape?

Comment: That's... not what a `(1, 3)` shape means, and a `[n, [1, 3]]` shape isn't a thing. You might be able to use a structured array, but I suggest flattening the nested tuples.

Comment: I completely forgot about the flatten function haha thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather use a `n x 4` dimensional `numpy` array. The first axis allows you to choose between different results of the `getcolors` method. The second axis contains your data. You can store in the first entry the `count` value, and then the `r`, `g` and the `b` value. Then you can do something like this:

```
result = np.empty(number, 4)
#get one entry
count, r, g, b = result[n]
```

You should always keep in mind, what you are acutally trying to do: The data you want to store contains 4 different integers, so it is 4-dimensional. And you expect `n` different data points of this type. Therefore, your array has to have the shape `n x 4`.

PS: You use a strange definition of shapes' dimension; this causes you a lot of trouble. I suggest using the default definition of shapes, and thinking about them as the axes of a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try flattening the tuples and trying this! And yeah, after messing around with numpy's empty method, I realized I didn't fully understand the shape format